# Forge Viewer API: Bounding box for a specific element

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I am using the following method for determining the bounding box of a specific element:

```
MyViewer.select( [dbId]); var box = MyViewer.utilities.getBoundingBox();
```

This works but I wonder if there is a direct function to do this (similar to how getBulkProperties work), especially when I am running through a large number of dbIds in a loop.

I also figured out that I can do this by finding the list of fragments of the element and calculating bounding box of each to calculate element's bounding box. That is more work.

Thanks
Bandu

Answer (score 1):

@Bandu,
I do not find any more direct method, but maybe the code function below could be of use?

```
 function getModifiedWorldBoundingBox (fragIds) {

        //fragments list array
        var fragList = NOP_VIEWER.model.getFragmentList();
        const fragbBox = new THREE.Box3()
        const nodebBox = new THREE.Box3()

        fragIds.forEach(function(fragId) { 
           fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, fragbBox) 
           nodebBox.union(fragbBox)
        })

    return nodebBox
 }
```