# How to control the distance between the page and the component with FitToView?

Tags: autodesk-forge

After using FitToView, the distance between the page and the component is too close. Is there any good method to control this distance?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yxqV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could get the boundingbox of the object (components) and scale up/down with the box to make an appropriate box and call fitBounds

getBoundingbox:
[Forge Viewer API: Bounding box for a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035030/forge-viewer-api-bounding-box-for-a-specific-element)

fitBounds:
[Autodesk forge viewer zooming to bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282331/autodesk-forge-viewer-zooming-to-bounding-box)