# Is it possible to change the zoom factor of the fitToVIew function?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.html#fitToView

I want to change the zoom factor because it's so close to the object. Are there any workaround to this? There doesn't seem to be a parameter regarding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not changeable, but you could get the object bounding box and scale it to a proper size that matches your desired camera location.

See also:
[How to control the distance between the page and the component with FitToView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856689/how-to-control-the-distance-between-the-page-and-the-component-with-fittoview)