# I'm trying to use Autodesk.Viewing.Navigation.fitBounds but an uncaught error came up

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

So I was trying to use the combination of getBoundingbox and fitBounds as per this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856689/how-to-control-the-distance-between-the-page-and-the-component-with-fittoview), but this error comes up:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fov')
    at Navigation.getVerticalFov (UnitFormatter.js:320:1)
    at Navigation.fitBounds (SnapResult.js:87:1)
    at Array.<anonymous> (index.ts:1100:25)
    at propertyWorkerCallback (LeafletLoader.js:42:1)
    at Worker.callbackFn (PropDbLoader.js:151:1)
```

I don't know how to debug it. I'm not aware of the 'fov' or why it's undefined.

This is a sample of how the code looks like

```
const boundingBox = extension.getBoundingBox(dbId)
window.navigation.fitBounds(true, boundingBox, true, true);
```

getBoundingBox is like this:

```
getBoundingBox = (dbId: number): THREE.Box3 => {
  const fragIds = this.getFragmentIds(dbId);
  const fragList = this.viewer.model.getFragmentList();
  const fragBox = new THREE.Box3();
  const nodeBox = new THREE.Box3();
  fragIds.forEach((fragId) => {
    fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, fragBox);
    nodeBox.union(fragBox);
  });
  return nodeBox;
};
```

Navigation.fitBounds:  https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#fitbounds-immediate-bounds-reorient-force

Comment: The documentation link you provided is for the viewer v6. I suppose that you use the viewer v7. Here's the link [FitBounds](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#fitbounds-immediate-bounds-reorient-force). As described in the documentation, the 4 parameters - immediate / bounds / reorient / force - are required.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. Let me edit my question. As far as the error, it is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a model. It looks working well, Could you check if I missed any steps to reproduce your problem. If it happens with specific model, please share us a demo model at aps.help @ autodesk.com

[image]